# Powershell command with where clause coming from variable

Tags: powershell

I have an issue while working with where clause when using variable for that purpose. My where clause is dynamic thus I worked out that way:

```
$server_FS_exclusions = @("print$","prnproc$","Scripts$","Logs$")
foreach ($exc in $server_FS_exclusions) {$exc_where += "(`$_.Name -ne '$exc') -and "}
$where = $exc_where.Substring(0,$exc_where.LastIndexOf(" -and "))
    
Get-WmiObject -Query 'SELECT * FROM Win32_Share Where Type=0' -ComputerName XYZ | where {$where}
```

Unfortunatelly this does not work as expected but does no throw any error. It behave like where clause does not exist or not match conditions.
However when I write the same command to console and get the output

```
Write-Host  "Get-WmiObject -Query 'SELECT * FROM Win32_Share Where Type=0' -ComputerName XYZ | where {$where}"
```

and finally use that directly in console it works perfectly.

```
Get-WmiObject -Query 'SELECT * FROM Win32_Share Where Type=0' -ComputerName XYZ | where {($_.Name -ne 'print$') -and ($_.Name -ne 'prnproc$') -and ($_.Name -ne 'Scripts$') -and ($_.Name -ne 'Logs$')}
```

I guessing the issue might be related to quoting strings but I'm not sure how I should deal with this.
Any help appreciated :)

Comment: instead of building your string and then removing the final `-and` ... use the `-join` operator. that will only put the delimiter string/char _between_ the items.

Comment: Just do `Where-Object { $_.Name -notin $server_FS_exclusions }` or `Where-Object { $server_FS_exclusions -notcontains $_.Name }` and forget about the rest. Also, you don't need `@()` when defining the exclusions array and I would advise to single quote the elements like `$server_FS_exclusions = 'print$','prnproc$','Scripts$','Logs$'`

Comment: Thank you, now it looks more simple and more elegant then I thought. Of course now it's working as expected.

Comment: You'd have to say `invoke-expression $where` for that to work, not the most ideal.